# Do we need to change page headers (Register/Assembly name versions?) when upgrading a SharePoint 2010 webpart to SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

Do we need to change the version numbers of the code present in the head of the page of webpart?

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>   
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" TagPrefix="cc2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Example from 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0?

We have already done:-

1. Edit .csproj file and add to it -> 15.0
2. Go to project properties and set framework as 4.5
3. Go to package and under properties of the package set the version to 15.0
4. Check each file to do a check for any hive references. You'll need to add a /15/ to 
   these. EG: _layouts/ to _layouts/15/ and also for _images
5. Download AJAX version 4.5 and update reference of AJAX dll in project
6. Do right click on project and Click Clean to clean solution
7. Build the solution, then Deploy your solution

Comment: I did update 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0 and it did work in SP2013, jsut want to confirm this is good practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no, it is not *strictly* needed". SharePoint actually will perform a sort of implicit assembly redirection so even if you reference the v14 assembly at runtime the v15 references will be loaded. That said, it is often preferred to fix the version numbers in case some redirection goes wrong  (or you are so lucky to find out the only single assembly for which Microsoft forgot to add redirect rules).

For a more appropriate description of how redirection works you may have a look at [this blog](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.it/2011_09_01_archive.html) who does a good work at explaining. Basically, SharePoint uses a mix of web.config based redirection and publisher policy files based rules. In the end, from an user perspective the result is the same - your v14 SharePoint assembly references will get remapped to v15.